# Publishing from Visual Studio 2015 Community into SharePoint 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to publish an app from VS 2015 Community to SharePoint 2013 running locally. I am getting an error that "the load balancer is not provisioned. Verify the load balancer was provisioned successfully".

How do I provision the load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have a service that is not fully deployed. Check the ULS logs to find out which service that is.  Then remove it and add it back.

If this were production - depending on the service, you would still start with ULS, but probably look to troubleshoot it further (and most likely just re-provision the proxy).

Comment: Please forgive me is the ULS logs the same thing as looking at the Event Viewer? My event viewer shows a number of errors which probably have a bearing on my SharePoint instance.

Comment: ULS is where SharePoint logs more detailed events.  Do a search for ULS troubleshooting and you will get a lot of resources to help you.  Start here - he has a pretty good break down http://www.wservernews.com/newsletters/archives/sharepoint-troubleshooting-101-11083.html#EC